# What is the equivalent of NSString.stringWithContentsOfURL in Monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm missing `NSString.stringWithContentsOfURL` in Monotouch. Does it exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even easier:

```
string msg = new WebClient ().DownloadString ("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: I think that NSString stringWithContentsOfURL takes into consideration auto proxies, but WebClient (well, WebRequest) does not. 

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?&id=1081

Answer (score 3):

[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:] is not bound in monotouch.

You could invoke it manually like this:

```
var url = new NSUrl ("http://www.google.com/");
var str = (NSString) Runtime.GetNSObject (Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (Class.GetHandle ("NSString"), Selector.GetHandle ("stringWithContentsOfURL:"), url.Handle));
```

Comment: `Runtime` is in the `ObjCRuntime`namespace but I can't find `Messaging`, would you mind adding the namespaces?